# Sending multiple post requests with sim800C

Tags: sim900, sim800

I am working on the sim800C board, primarily on sending HTTP post requests.

As I understand from manual and samples online, the process of sending a post request with AT commands involves:

1. Configuring Bearers: open a bearer and set it up:

   `AT+SAPBR=3,1,"APN","CMNET";+SAPBR=1,1;`
2. Do HTTPINIT and then set up parameters:

   `AT+HTTPINIT;+HTTPPARA="CID",1;+HTTPPARA="URL","example.url";+HTTPPARA="CONTENT","application/json";`
3. Set request body size and timeout then input the data

   ```
   AT+HTTPDATA=90,10000
   {"test":"test-conent"}
   ```
4. Start post session and read response(if needed. In my case, I only care about status code)

   `AT+HTTPACTION=1`
5. Terminate HTTP service and close bearer

   ```
   AT+HTTPTERM
   ```
6. Close bearer

   ```
   AT+SAPBR=0,1
   ```

My question is, are any of these steps **reusable** if I'm sending multiple post requests? Closing and re-opening the bearer over and over can be really time-consuming, compared with other settings steps.

I have tried using the same bearer for multiple requests but got 601 status code after the first one. Is there a workaround to reuse the same bearer but still make multiple posts wit it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer myself after testing: **step 2-5** are reusable.